# Special characters showing in fallback font

Tags: customization, widgets, css, encoding

I have created a widget that displays some text using a custom font imported with CSS @font-face. The font **have support** for scandinavian characters åäö, but when I display these characters in my widget it looks like they fallback to another font.

The text is all wrapped in the same element, no individual styling for the special characters.

[image: custom font problem]

This problem occurs when I get the text from the widget instance object. If I just echo text with these special characters then there's no issue.

In the widget's *update()* function I run strip_tags() with the text inputted by a user, then store it in the widget instance.

```
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
    $instance['text'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['text'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['text'] ) : '';
    return $instance;
}
```

In *widget()* where the text is printed it's not manipulated in any way before being printed:

```
public function widget($args, $instance) {
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    $text = $instance['text'];
    if (!empty( $title)) echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
    if (!empty($text)) echo $text;
    echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```

How to make text from the widget's field data display properly?

**EDIT:** Seems like it's an encoding issue. Used asciivalue.com to lookup an ö character that I get from the widget field, and compare it to an ö character that I look up. The result for string "ö ö", with the first one(**not** working) being from the widget and the second one(working) input directly by me:

[image: ASCII lookup]

Comment: Which font are you using, and exactly how? Most probably the font you are actually importing does not have letters like “ä”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela thanks for commenting, but I have stated in the question that the font have support for the characters. The support is there, and it's working well when I just echo the characters. But not working when I get the text through my widget.

Comment: So you are saying that things work, but they don’t, right? You are not giving any facts or any way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I hear you. Edited the question to make it more clear, and added some relevant code from my WP_Widget subclass.

Comment: Live demo might be in order. It does sound like it _should_ work given that it is expected character in text.

Comment: @Rarst alright, I'll see if I can set up a live demo tomorrow. I thought this was a common problem with widgets, but seems like it isn't.

Comment: How do you get the ö into the widget? Depending on that it is a WordPress issue or a general encoding problem. Note, there are two ways to encode that character: one character and a combination of the letter o + diaresis. The latter isn’t well supported and it should not be used anywhere.

Comment: @toscho I input it with my keyboard through the Wordpress admin interface, under widgets. My widget accepts input there, store it and then my theme displays it.

Comment: Look at both variants with a hex editor, and the characters to your question please.

Comment: @toscho don't my edit with the ascii lookup already address this though?

Comment: @toscho according to that output it looks like it's the o with diaresis... 776: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm Now that I think of it I actually didn't input it manually, but copy-pasted from a PDF. Problem solved!